# Clarification over notation for derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

I have the following expression $f = \mathbf{Wa}$, and I would like to differentiate with respect to $\mathbf{a}$. What is the correct way to write down the whole operation? If I write the following is it a mistake: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} = \frac{ \partial \mathbf{Wa}}{\partial a} = \mathbf{W}$$

Is that correct? How can I write it properly? W is a matrix $M \times N$ while w a vector $N \times 1$.

Comment: Looks right to me

Comment: How many indices are on each of $\mathbf{W},\,\mathbf{a}$? Is there any significance to $\partial/\partial a$ lacking bold, or is that a misprint each time?

Comment: W is a matrix $M \times N$ while w a vector $N \times 1$.

Comment: there is no w in your formula.

Comment: @miracle173 ??? It was a typo W my matrix and a my vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $W$ entries don't depend on $a$ entries, $f_i=W_{ij}a_j\implies\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial a_j}=W_{ij}$, i.e. $\frac{\partial\mathbf{f}}{\partial\mathbf{a}}=\mathbf{W}$ (or $\mathbf{W}^T$, depending on how vector-vector derivatives are defined as a matter of convention).

Comment: So the notation is correct? I got feedback in the exercise that my notation is not correct.

Comment: @JoseRamon My comment on the OP noted one notational issue, but the bottom line is you need an index-based justification viz. my answer; you can't just write down a "top-level" manipulation & hope it's obvious it's correct.

Comment: So the notation is correct but does not hold any explanation.

Comment: If entries of $W$ depend on why the result is $W^{T}$? Is not it a completely different matrix (with partial derivatives)? Is not it a 3d tensor in this case?

Comment: @JoseRamon Since $\mathbf{f},\,\mathbf{a}$ are vectors, $\frac{\partial\mathbf{f}}{\partial\mathbf{a}}$ is a matrix, not a rank-$3$ tensor. *Which* matrix is a matter of convention, i.e. an arbitrary decision in how we *define* $\frac{\partial\mathbf{f}}{\partial\mathbf{a}}$.

Comment: Hey yes indeed you are right, I am trying to figure out why we have the transpose in the result. Is it for instance, if the convention is 'Denominator' where the derivative of a scalar over a vector is a row vector?

Comment: If W is depending on a isn't that the result is not W but another matrix of the same size also?

Comment: @JoseRamon As I said, $\partial f_i/\partial a_j=W_{ij}$. Now you just have to decide whether to define $\frac{\partial\mathbf{f}}{\partial\mathbf{a}}$ to have ${}_{ij}$ entry $\partial f_i/\partial a_j$ or $\partial f_j/\partial a_i$. An easy exercise tells you which obtains the desirable $d\mathbf{f}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{f}}{\partial\mathbf{a}}d\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: @JoseRamon Having said that, we'd need to transpose that choice of matrix to represent the multivariable chain rule with row vectors instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less correct, but I would suggest making it slightly more clear by putting parenthesis in the middle step like this:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \textbf{a}} = \frac{\partial (\textbf{Wa})}{\partial \textbf{a}}=\textbf{W}$$

As a side note, whether or not you put $\textbf{a}$ in bold was inconsistent. Based on the comments it seemed like that was a mistake and it should have been in bold everywhere, so I formatted it like that in my answer.